# Gnuplot loop over data in file

Tags: loops, gnuplot

I have datafile `mydata` :

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want to manually sum them all up and calculate the average. So something like this:

```
sum = 0
do for [i in "mydata"] {
    sum = sum + i
}
print(sum/6)    # expected 6
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that manually? Use `stats "mydata"; print STATS_mean`

Comment: I want to have a general way at hand to iterate and use all values. The calculation here is just an example in which kind of way I might use it.